# What a correct type for array of interface with generic?

Tags: typescript

How to set correct type for routes array in this example to avoid error:

`TS2314: Generic type 'Route ' requires 1 type argument(s).`

[code in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukA8AVAPmQG8AoZZABzjAAsAuZAZzClAHNzla4QATADbRGACgCUyALxE8pAL6lSCAXCZM0WSFBJcomiE0YZsEANoBdKcguKKcPn2O5CI6nUYs2IdgBpuvQWENE3wCUwByHn4hKHDzCTIKCjpgJgA6PRN0ykwmWhFEpIo3Wh8uIqjAqHLkOTEuBQUldBAWZEytKxAIAHdgrXFSDug0%200d9HE8OAhFI9ABbCHC-cSkicIBGACYAZnD6oA)

```
interface Route<T> {
  path: string
  handler: () => T
}

class Router {
  routes: Route[] = []

  addRoute<T>(path: string, handler: Route<T>['handler']) {
    this.routes.push({
      path,
      handler
    })
  }
}

const router = new Router()
router.addRoute<string>('home', () => '123')
```

Comment: Doesnt the error message say it all? You cant have an array of `Route` without specifying the type. If you're storing different types,, you'll possibly need `Route<any>[]` (or narrow it down to specific types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukA8AVAPmQG8AoZZABzjAAsAuZAZzClAHNzla4QATADbRGACgCUyALxE8pAL6lSCAXCZM0WSFBJcomiE0YZsEHJhABrEOgDuIAgG0AulOTPFFOHz7HchEdR0jCxsIOwANNy8gsIaJviOAOQ8-EJQiU4SZBQUdMBMAHR6JoWUmEy0Itk5FIG04Vw1KTFQjchyYlwKCkroICzIxVquIBA2cVripEPQBV4++iKJMOjoiZHiUkSJAIwATADMiZ0zUHPevhBLAEZw6RsS0sj7B52kAPTvyOitSipqE2gewSOgoM0MgISzlc7i480uARoDGYrA4kWaaSM+ihyWiaQyWTaeUK4IKZQqVTatSRDRqFAx0DaHS68kUCD6A1OewAyqwRmNAVBgSEOAQplzeWd4YtErcAF7rZCbJ67Q7HNkcsCDfRCgBymAAtvzxpchTgQIbrtAxScdXt9QbzgsTEsAI6YYAKh5bZ6HMRAA)

```js
interface Route<T> {
  path: string
  handler: () => T
}

class Router {
  routes: Route<unknown>[] = []

  addRoute<T>(path: string, handler: Route<T>['handler']) {
    this.routes.push({
      path,
      handler
    })
  }
}

const router = new Router()
router.addRoute('foo', () => '123')
router.addRoute('bar', () => 123)

// or

class Router2<T> {
  routes: Route<T>[] = []

  addRoute(path: string, handler: Route<T>['handler']) {
    this.routes.push({
      path,
      handler
    })
  }
}

const router2Str = new Router2<string>()
router2Str.addRoute('baz', () => '123')

const router2Num = new Router2<number>()
router2Num.addRoute('quiz', () => 123)
```